# Expressing a constraint of the form $\max(x_1,x_2) \ge q$ in a linear program

Tags: discrete-mathematics, linear-programming, integer-programming

I am trying to solve an LP in which one of the constraints is mentioned below,
$$\max(x_1,x_2) \ge q,$$
where $x_1 \ge 0$ and $x_2 \ge 0$.

Is it possible to do in linear programming?

Comment: The feasible set of an LP is convex, since it is the intersection of half spaces, which are convex. The set defined by $\max(x_1,x_2)\geq q,x_1\geq 0,x_2\geq0$ is non-convex for  $q>0$. This is because $(x_1,x_2)=(q,0)$ and $(0,q)$ belong to the set, but $\frac{1}{2}\left((q,0)+(0,q)\right)=(q/2,q/2)$ doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

No. If you could do that in linear programming then you could force a variable to have binary values, so you'd be able to solve integer linear programs using LP solvers.

Indeed, we can simulate $x \in \{0,1\}$ with:

$$
\max\{x, 1-x\} \ge 1, \\
x \ge 0, \\
x \le 1.
$$

Comment: Thanks Steven for your reply. 
Could you elaborate a bit more the following inequalities given x is a binary variable?

$$max \{x,1−x\} ≥1$$

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on what's not clear? Besides, $x$ is not a binary variable. It is a continuous variable between $0$ and $1$ (inclusive). This, combined with the constraint $\max\{x,1−x\} \ge 1$ forces $x$ to be either $0$ or $1$. You can check that, for $x \in \{0,1\}$, the constraint $\max \{x, 1-x\} \ge 1$  is satisfied since $\max\{x, 1-x\}=1$. For $0<x<1$ you have $\max\{x,1−x\}<1$, which violates the constraint. Does this clear your doubts?

Comment: got it. I though x is a binary variable (as you used curly bracket).